# a beahviour of a simple function that i cannot wrap my head around?

Tags: php, function, static

this is an example function from a book to introduce `static` variabls.

```
  1 <?php                                                                                                          
  2     function test()                                                                                            
  3     {                                                                                                          
  4         static $count = 0;                                                                                     
  5         echo $count;                                                                                           
  6         $count++;                                                                                              
  7     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  8 ?>
```

now if i called `test` 2 times, like this:

```
  1 <?php                                                                                                          
  2     function test()                                                                                            
  3     {                                                                                                          
  4         static $count = 0;                                                                                     
  5         echo $count;                                                                                           
  6         $count++;                                                                                              
  7     }                                                                                                          
  8                                                                                                                
  9     test();                                                                                                    
 10     test();                                                                                                    
 11                                                                                                                
 12 ?>
```

i would expect the output to be like this:

```
0
1
```

instead, the output is :

```
└─$ php static.php
01
```

why is this?

Comment: You aren't printing line returns, so `0` and `1` are printed next to each other, call your function one more time and you will see `012`.

Comment: @AymDev makes sense. so changing `echo $count;` to `echo $count . "\n"` or `"<br>"` will do

Comment: Print a `<br>` if you are testing on a web browser, but I think you are executing your code from the CLI SAPI (command line), you can print a new line with the `PHP_EOL` constant which will take care of operating system differences.

Answer (score 2):

didn't add a newline character:
`echo $count;` to ->  `echo $count . "\n"`